# change 3rd character in a line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

input:

```
dummy - 22847847
sha - 84734747
DHS - 374874
```

expected output:

```
du1my - 22847847
sh1 - 84734747
DH1 - 374874
```

Comment: The example does not change every 3rd character, it changes only the 3rd character (on each line).

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\(..\)./\11/' infile > expected_result
```

The `(..)` is known as a group match and it capture first two characters and the `\1` is its back-reference. dot `.` in regular expression matches any single character.

if that was not 3<sup>rd</sup> place but N<sup>th</sup>, you could do as following to change the 3<sup>rd</sup> place character with `1`.

```
sed 's/^\(.\{2\}\)./\11/' infile
```

Or just like below as pointed by [@steeldriver](/65304/steeldriver):

```
sed 's/./1/3' infile
```

Comment: Why not just `s/./1/3`?

Comment: @steeldriver I totally forgot that :     ).

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat test.txt
dummy - 22847847
sha - 84734747
DHS - 374874

$ awk '{$3=1}1' FS="" OFS="" test.txt
du1my - 22847847
sh1 - 84734747
DH1 - 374874
```